# Check if object is in manytomany list in template

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I check if a certain object/id is in a list?

I want something to be displayed if the ID of the connected object is not "6".

Tried with something like this:

```
 {% if user.benefits.all != "6" %}
    You do not have a benefit with ID 6.
 {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to **not** put much logic into templates. View (or model) - is a better place for that.

For example in view you can check, that user.benefits has element with id=6 by this code:

```
has_benefit = user.benefits.filter(id=6).count() > 0
context['has_benefit'] = has_benefit
```

Now in template just use this new context variable:

```
{% if not has_benefit %}
    You do not have a benefit with ID 6.
{% endif %}
```

**UPDATED**:

If you still want to do it in template, it is better to create a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='has_benefit')
def has_benefit(user, benefit_id):
    b_id = int(benefit_id)
    return user.benefits.filter(id=b_id).count() > 0
```

Now in template load your templatetags module using `{% load module_name %}` and use:

```
{% if not user|has_benefit:"6" %}
    You do not have a benefit with ID 6.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I'll try to do this in the view.

Answer (score 2):

```
{% for benefit in user.benefits.all %}
    {% if benefit.id != 6 %}
        You do not have a benefit with id 6
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But this will loop through all the benefits and print it every time the condition passes.

So, you should write a template tag which returns you a list of ids for all benefits for a particular user and once you have that list you can do:

```
{% if 6 not in list_of_benefit_ids %}
    You do not have a benefit with id 6
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Okay, I was hoping I could skip another for loop. But guess not.

Comment: @Garreth00 You should perform this check in the view and not in the template. You should always just put out data that's "filtered" and done to the template.